# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, autowired

I have a problem that I can't handle on my own. I have tried everything that is possible (in my opinion). I really need your help, because I don't have any ideas.

I have this error:

```
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'web.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'web.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

...

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'web.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

...
```

My code:

> interface UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

> class UserService

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }

        return user;
    }

    public User findUserById(Long userId) {
        Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
        return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
    }

    public List<User> allUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
    ...
}
```

> class SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "web")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("userService")
UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll();

        http.logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/admin_panel")
                .access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

> My folder hierarchy:

[image]

Help please...
For several days I'm trying to create Spring Security CRUD application. I'm confused. I can't solve this errors.

Comment: can you please share your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz But I don't use SprinBoot

Comment: You need a @EnableJpaRepositories in your spring config that contains the packagename for your repos. Otherwise your repos won't be picked up by the spring container.

Comment: ok. Is there any reason speaking against?

Comment: @MichaelKreutz yes. in this task I should not use Springboot(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable JpaRepositories configuration, add the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to your configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("web.repositories")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

   @Bean  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
     // put here your favourite entity manager factory
   }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your response. That solved my problem. But there was another problem: caused by: org. spring frame.green bean.plant.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: no bean named 'entityManagerFactory' not available

Comment: its up to you to define such entity. In particular regarding which are your requirement about transactions and a bunch of other stuff.
I suggest you to read the reference documenttion about [spring jpa repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)